# Masking SVG with blur produces ugly results

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have rectangles / paths as rectangles with a glow effect. That works well as long as I do not mask the inner part (i.e. hiding either the filling or the glowing inside of the rectangles). Masking part of the objects produces some ugly effect of the previously smooth glow.

So, applying the mask seems to render the previous "image" somehow. Is there a way to avoid this? If not, are there alternatives?

```html
<svg id="button-glow" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    
    <defs>

      <filter id="cyan-glow" x="-5000%" y="-5000%" width="10000%" height="10000%">
          <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#00e4ff" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
          <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
          <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
          <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
          <feMerge>
              <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
              <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
          </feMerge>
      </filter>
      
     
      <mask id="Mask1">
        <rect x="-100" y="-100" width="250" height="250" fill="white"  />
        <rect x="3" y="3" width="34" height="34" fill="black"  />
      </mask>
        
     <mask id="Mask2">
        <rect x="-100" y="-100" width="250" height="250" fill="white"  />
        <rect x="3" y="3" width="34" height="34" fill="black"  />
      </mask>
        
    </defs>
    
    <g transform="translate(20,20)">
        <rect x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40" fill="#00e4ff"/>
        
        <rect transform="translate(60,0)" x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40"
              fill="#00e4ff" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)"/>
        
        <rect transform="translate(120,0)" x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40"
              fill="#00e4ff" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" mask="url(#Mask1)"/>
     
        <path transform="translate(0,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
     
        <path transform="translate(60,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" fill="none"/>

        <path transform="translate(120,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" fill="none" mask="url(#Mask2)"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ugly effect"?

Comment: The gradient is cut off half-way around the edges. I expected it to smooth out the same way as it does without the mask. With `x="-100" y="-100" width="250" height="250"` I considered the mask to be wide enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the masks bigger.

You'd also be better off making the filter smaller. The huge filter size is why your SVG is very slow to render.

```html
<svg id="button-glow" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    
    <defs>

      <filter id="cyan-glow" x="-5000%" y="-5000%" width="10000%" height="10000%">
          <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#00e4ff" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
          <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
          <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
          <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
          <feMerge>
              <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
              <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
          </feMerge>
      </filter>
      
     
      <mask id="Mask1" x="-40%" y="-40%" width="180%" height="180%">
        <rect x="-100" y="-100" width="250" height="250" fill="white"  />
        <rect x="3" y="3" width="34" height="34" fill="black"  />
      </mask>
        
     <mask id="Mask2" x="-40%" y="-40%" width="180%" height="180%">
        <rect x="-100" y="-100" width="250" height="250" fill="white"  />
        <rect x="3" y="3" width="34" height="34" fill="black"  />
      </mask>
        
    </defs>
    
    <g transform="translate(20,20)">
        <rect x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40" fill="#00e4ff"/>
        
        <rect transform="translate(60,0)" x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40"
              fill="#00e4ff" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)"/>
        
        <rect transform="translate(120,0)" x="0" y="0"  width="40" height="40"
              fill="#00e4ff" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" mask="url(#Mask1)"/>
     
        <path transform="translate(0,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
     
        <path transform="translate(60,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" fill="none"/>

        <path transform="translate(120,60)" d="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 L0,40 z" stroke="#00e4ff"
              stroke-width="3" style="filter:url(#cyan-glow)" fill="none" mask="url(#Mask2)"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it! Will also modify the filter according to your advice!